# Different result for Image width and height each time in JQuery

Tags: jquery, image, height, client, width

Its very weird for me, as I'm changing width and height of the loaded image which run in document.ready(). 
Every time the function runs,the image width and height is different.

I use this code for getting width and height for loaded image :

```
    var img = document.getElementById('imgLogo');
    var width = img.clientWidth;
    var height = img.clientHeight;
```

This is the code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  SetLogo();
});

function SetLogo() {

  var src = 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.sm.jpg';
  $('#imgLogo').attr("src", src);

  if (src == "") {

    $('#dvimg').addClass("hidden");
  } else {

    $('#dvimg').removeClass("hidden");

    var panel = document.getElementById('dvimg');
    var pwidth = panel.clientWidth;
    var pheigh = panel.clientHeight;

    var img = document.getElementById('imgLogo');
    alert("image w= " + $('#imgLogo').width() + " image H= " + $('#imgLogo').height());


    var ratio = img.clientWidth / img.clientHeight;

    if (img.clientWidth > pwidth) {
      alert('width > pwidth');
      $('#imgLogo').height(pwidth / ratio);
      $('#imgLogo').width(pwidth);

      $('#dvimg').css("padding-top", (pheigh - img.clientHeight) / 2);
      $('#dvimg').css("padding-left", 0);
    } else if (img.clientHeight > pheigh) {

      alert('height > pheigh');

      $('#imgLogo').height(pheigh);
      $('#imgLogo').width(pheigh * ratio);

      $('#dvimg').css("padding-left", (pwidth - img.clientWidth) / 2);

      $('#dvimg').css("padding-top", 0);
    } else {
      alert('else');
      $('#dvimg').css("padding-top", (pheigh - img.clientHeight) / 2);
      $('#dvimg').css("padding-left", (pwidth - img.clientWidth) / 2);

    }

    alert("image heigh after change : " + img.clientHeight + "image width after change : " + img.clientWidth);

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dvimg" class="col-md-12 panel mbl text-center" style="height: 300px; width: 400px;">
  <img id="imgLogo" src="images/blank.jpg" />
</div>
```

Also, the result is different in each browser.

Thank you in advanced for any help.

Comment: Try using innerWidth & innerHeight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image has to load first which is not yet the case on document ready - if the it isn't cached. That's why it's returning  a rather randowm number the first time the page is loaded.

For it to always be correct, run the function inside a `$(window).on('load', function() { ... })`.

Edit - I see something tricky now about the code though. You can't run the whole function after the window loads because appending the `src` happens inside the function itself. So it's better to take it out and target the loading of the logo alone (`.one()` is a variation of `.on()` that fires a single time) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var src = 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.sm.jpg';
  $('#imgLogo').attr("src", src);

  $('#imgLogo').one('load', function() {SetLogo()});

  function SetLogo(){

  ...

  }
});
```

Full snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var src = 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/3.sm.jpg';
  $('#imgLogo').attr("src", src);

  $('#imgLogo').one('load', function() {
    SetLogo()
  });

  function SetLogo() {

    if (src == "") {

      $('#dvimg').addClass("hidden");
    } else {

      $('#dvimg').removeClass("hidden");

      var panel = document.getElementById('dvimg');
      var pwidth = panel.clientWidth;
      var pheigh = panel.clientHeight;

      var img = document.getElementById('imgLogo');
      alert("image w= " + $('#imgLogo').width() + " image H= " + $('#imgLogo').height());


      var ratio = img.clientWidth / img.clientHeight;

      if (img.clientWidth > pwidth) {
        alert('width > pwidth');
        $('#imgLogo').height(pwidth / ratio);
        $('#imgLogo').width(pwidth);

        $('#dvimg').css("padding-top", (pheigh - img.clientHeight) / 2);
        $('#dvimg').css("padding-left", 0);
      } else if (img.clientHeight > pheigh) {

        alert('height > pheigh');

        $('#imgLogo').height(pheigh);
        $('#imgLogo').width(pheigh * ratio);

        $('#dvimg').css("padding-left", (pwidth - img.clientWidth) / 2);

        $('#dvimg').css("padding-top", 0);
      } else {
        alert('else');
        $('#dvimg').css("padding-top", (pheigh - img.clientHeight) / 2);
        $('#dvimg').css("padding-left", (pwidth - img.clientWidth) / 2);

      }

      alert("image heigh after change : " + img.clientHeight + "image width after change : " + img.clientWidth);

    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dvimg" class="col-md-12 panel mbl text-center" style="height: 300px; width: 400px;">
  <img id="imgLogo" src="images/blank.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: I change the fiddle as your suggestion. but no changes. I mean the code is running in each load. I dont know why in the fiddle , the result is abit different. I will be appreciate if you could test it in a separate webpage.after pressing Ctrl+F5 the new width and height are 24! what does that mean?

Comment: Any particular browser or device? FF, IE, Chrome and Opera all seem to work correctly on my setup. Even after clearing the cache and Ctrl+F5. Pasted in Codepen as well. Maybe you could provide a link to what you're describing (so I can check the code)...

Comment: It works most of the times after I moved the "SetLogo" code into the doc.ready(). but whats the issue when I press Ctrl+F5? why the image's not responding well?

Comment: You'd have to provide a bit more info - browser, device setup or maybe a link where the issue can be seen because I cannot replicate it. Sounds like something specific to the setup or possible server side caching.

Comment: I guess it's the image on the right... don't see anything unusual about it myself apart from resizing being visible on Firefox. Did many cache refreshes on four types of browsers, Windows 7 desktop.

Comment: what about this version? I updated the code. I guess when I use alert in my code, it shown correctly . now I've replaced it with textbox. every now and then, the width and heigh have very strange values. could u please check it?

Comment: Looks logical to me - the original dimensions of the image, it's just that width and height are reversed. But that would be something simple in the coding that shows the info.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, then I mark your answer as correct one , because I guess there's a problem with my settings. I will be thankful if you could have a chance to reply any further suggestions.

Comment: Cheers, I see it's this line : `... "w=" + img.clientHeight + " and h=" + img.clientWidth;`. So it should work fine just display it incorrectly. More importantly, I think you may have missed the last characters with copy and paste. The script ends with `}` on that page when it should be `});`. So the function isn't closed properly.